# Get column component object in toggleEvent using columnToggler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem getting Column component object.

Here is the logic that should be implemented:

1. user toggles table columns using primefaces columnToggler (when user clicks on checkbox, ajax listener method is called)
2. in listener method, I have to retrieve Column component object and call method that stores Column component object and it's visibility parameters in database, so it can be retrieved when page loads.

Basically this is just a simple user-unique checkbox-column-visibility "remember" thing.

Now, everything is fine, I am calling ajax listener method when user toggles one of the checkboxes:

```
<p:commandButton id="columnToggler" type="button" value="Columns"/>
<p:columnToggler datasource="grid" trigger="columnToggler">
<p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{bean.onColumnToggle}"/>
</p:columnToggler>
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to get Column component object, because unlike cellEditEvent, toggleEvent has no getColumn() method that returns Column object.

Does anyone have an idea how to get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Optional toggle ajax behavior is provided by columnChooser component
>   to listen to toggle events at server side. Listener of this behavior
>   gets an org.primefaces.event.ToggleEvent as a parameter that gives the
>   **visibility and index of the column being toggled**.

Please, try this example:

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
...
<p:commandButton id="columnToggler" type="button" value="Columns" />            
<p:columnToggler datasource="grid" trigger="columnToggler">
    <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{bean.onColumnToggle}" update="growl"/>
</p:columnToggler>
```

In your bean:

```
public void onColumnToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
    final Visibility visibility = event.getVisibility();
    final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();

    msg.setSummary("Column index " + event.getData().toString() + " toggled");
    msg.setDetail("Visibility: " + visibility);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that index part in documentation. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the methods of the datatable

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(formId).findComponent(tableId);
```

Take a look of the methods, there is one called getColumns which can be useful.